# Solving simultaneous equations with `min{}` function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have following system of `m` number of simultaneous equations with `min{}` function. These equations are symmetric as well.

```
x1=min{a+b*x2, c};
x2=min{a+b*x3, c};
.
.
.
xm=min{a+b*x1, c};
```

Is it necessary that `x1=x2=...=xm` must hold because of the symmetric nature of equations? Is there any theorem which proves or disproves the equivalence of the variables?

Comment: Look into [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Comment: As far as I understand(I, now, read a few links as well) Integer programming is about optimization. Isn't that different from solving simulateous equations ? Could you plz be more specific ?

Comment: I can't help you, I know little about integer programming, but I know it deals a lot with this sort of thing. I have no idea if it's actually helpful.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with integer programming.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider simpler similar system of equations

Let b <> 0 (otherwise, if b == 0, x1 = x2 = a)

`x1 = a + b*x2`

`x2 = a + b*x1`

from here you can find that

`x1 = x2 = a/(1-b), b <> 0`

And this solution will be effective for the system of equations:

`x1 = a + b*x2`

`x2 = a + b*x3`

`...`

`xn = a + b*x1`

and `x1 = x2 = x3 = ... = xn = a/(1-b)`

Now we can apply the results to your system of equations, and solution is:

`x1 = x2 =x3 = ... xn =`

`= a/(1-b)`, if **b <> 0** and **a/(1-b) < c**

`= c`, if **b <> 0** and **a/(1-b) >= c**

`= a`, if **b == 0** and **a < c**

`= c`, if **b == 0** and **a >= c**

Hope it helps